# retornar para view antes de executar a rota.. nodejs

Tags: node.js, view, rotas

Boa tarde pessoal como faço pra retornar pra view que disparou a rota sem 
executa-lá ?? segue abaaixo o trecho...

```
 app.post('/atendimentos/pesquisa', home.loggedIn, function (req, res) {

    var nome_pesquisa = req.body.cliente_pesquisa;
    var placa_pesquisa = req.body.placa_pesquisa;
    var sinistro_pesquisa = req.body.sinistro_pesquisa;



    //--- AQUI É FEIO O TESTE DA CONDIÇÃO
    if (nome_pesquisa == '' && placa_pesquisa == '' && sinistro_pesquisa == '') {
        return; ///------- ASSIM NAO FUNCIONA!! COMO SERIA???
    }



    modelAtendimento.pesquisaPrincipalAtendimentos(nome_pesquisa, placa_pesquisa, sinistro_pesquisa).then(result => {

        res.render('atendimentospesquisa', {
            atendimentos: result,
            nomepesquisado: nome_pesquisa,
            placapesquisada: placa_pesquisa,
            sinistropesquisado: sinistro_pesquisa,
            results: true,
            layout: 'layout'
        });

    });

});
```

caso nao tenho sido preenchi nenhum dos campos , desejo retornar pra view, inclusive se possível enviar a mensagem pra ela .....

obg, pessoal!!

Comment: Li sua pergunta agora, comecei a usar o SO-pt a pouco tempo, o que sei tento ajudar, no seu caso iria ajudar, mas você já se ajudou kkkk.

Comment: consegui com o próprio res.render(), só não consegui em enviar uma msg para a view ainda

Comment: Você pode até melhorar criando um middleware antes da execução da rota, middleware de validação de dados. Enviar mensagem para a view, explique melhor.

Comment: Opa valeu Anderson, la na view tem um <div alert> daí ao chegar retornar a mensagem que deve ser preenchido , mas fiz assim e ta funcionando... segue...

nao to conseguindo colocar codigo aqui como faço pra colocar as tags para codigos aqui em comentaários??

Comment: Coloca o código entre dois acento grave.

Comment: Tente usar o `res.redirect(rota)` antes do return. Ex: `res.redirect('/');`